# Can keybounce be caused by an incorrect driver?

Tags: keyboard, drivers, windows-98

I recently re-installed the OS on an old laptop, and just noticed that it seems to have some pretty bad keybounce.  Could that be that I need to find and install a driver for the keyboard, or is it more likely that it is just an old laptop and is wearing out?  I didn't notice the keybounce before the reinstall.

Comment: You could verify a hardware-error by using a Linux-Live-CD.

Comment: I really hoped to create a new tag here... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may just be the keyboard showing its age, though it could also be the repeat rate settings being wrong for some reason. Check these in the BIOS and OS (if you detail *which* OS you have installed we might be able to tell you where to look for the relevant settings).

Comment: Win98SE :(  Hey, I had the disks available, and I only need it for taking notes.  No internet, no games, no nothing.